# Navigation won't "break" or fall onto new row if centered

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a website for my cousin who does not know a single line of code. And I barely do :D

Well I can get my head around some basic stuff.

But I can't just seem to figure out how to do this Nav-bar. The problem that I face is I'm trying to make the website responsive. As it is now the code works fine when resizing the window to a smaller size (i.e the nav-bar stacks onto itself as supposed). BUT I want the four (4) links to be centered in relation to the header.

The header, as you will see has a padding on both sides of 13%. I then want the navbar to be centered in the remaining 74%. Hopefully this make any sense, I bet you guys are way better than me at doing this.

I do not have the website hosted yet so you will have to see the code for yourself.

I've tried to add `width:25%;` and `width:calc(100/4);` But when I add width to it, it gets centered as I want it to be, but it does not fall/break onto a new row, it glides into each other.

Thanks a massive for any help!

Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
        <title>Fanny Schwarz Design</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="header">
                <img src="main_img/fanny_schwarz_logo.jpg" class="logo" alt="Fanny Schwarz logo">
            </div>
            <div id="navigation">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="home.html">
                            &#9830;<span style="font-size:2em;">home</span>&#9830;
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="portfolio.html">
                            &#9830;<span style="font-size:2em;">portfolio</span>&#9830;
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="about.html">
                            &#9830;<span style="font-size:2em;">about</span>&#9830;
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="contact.html">
                            &#9830;<span style="font-size:2em;">contact</span>&#9830;
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="content">
                <h2>Page heading</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consect etuer adipi scing elit sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tinunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volut. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.</p>
                <p>Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
                <p>Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
            </div>
            <div id="footer">
                <div> 
                    <span style="vertical-align:middle; font-size:2em;">&copy;</span>
 <span style="font-size:1em; vertical-align:middle;">fanny schwarz 2014</span>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
body {
    background-color:#F9E1F7;
    font-family:monospace;
}
p {
    text-align:left;
}
#container {
    padding-left:13%;
    padding-right:13%;
    background:#F9E1F7;
    margin:0 auto;
}
#header {
    background:#ccc;
    text-align:none;
    max-height:290px;
}
.logo {
    position:relative;
    max-height:100%;
    max-width:100%;
    left:0;
}
#navigation {
    width:100%;
    background:#F9E1F7;
    letter-spacing:2px;
}
#navigation ul {
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#navigation ul li {
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
    display:inline-block;
    width: 25%;
}
#navigation li a {
    display:block;
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:10px;
}
#content {
    clear:left;
    padding:20px;
}
#content h2 {
    color:#000;
    font-size:160%;
    text-align:left;
    margin:0 0 .5em;
}
#footer {
    background:#F9E1F7;
    text-align:center;
    height:1%;
    font-size:15px;
    max-height:50px;
    line-height:50px;
    padding:20px;
}
#navigation li a:hover, #navigation li a:active {
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the CSS styles that were causing your problem:

```
#navigation ul {
overflow:hidden;
}

#navigation ul li {
float:left;
text-align:center;
width: 25%;
}
```

Change them to:

```
#navigation ul {
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;
}

#navigation ul li {
    list-style:none;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

That should fix your problem.  The reasons:

1. `overflow:hidden` will hide things that move out of your `li` on mobile browsers.
2. There's nothing wrong with `float:left`, except that you were trying to center the `li`s. You cannot do that when a `float:left` style is applied.
3. I think you meant to put `text-align:center` on the `ul`, not the `li`.
4. `width:25%` was causing your `li`s to overlap instead of breaking to the next line.

### [JSFIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/ianhazzard/Lzzjrobq/).

Hope this helps!